# Can I enter Canada in October 2019 with a passport that expires in February 2020?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, canada, us-citizens

Can I enter Canada from the US in October 2019 with my US passport that expires in February 2020?  I can not find specific requirements since the new rules were implemented. A link or website address for where the information can be found would be very helpful.

Comment: What "new rules" do you mean?